# Could we get any information from about class equation from index of sylow subgroups

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I have the class equation of a group of order $84$ 
as, 
 class equation  $84 = 1+1+12+21+21+28$ 
to check it is right or wrong 
i understands definition of class equation,

but what i wondering is that is there any way that if we knew about the Sylow subgroups of the group could we get any information about class equation

I can calculate index of Sylow subgroups

Comment: "Class equation" does not mean anything by itself: you have to precise which group action you take, and on which set.

Comment: Conjugacy class equation in group |G| = |Z(G)| + ∑ [G : C(xi)] where C(xi) is centralizer

Comment: @GreginGre I am fairly certain that most people will understand what is meant by class equation in this context.

Comment: An element in the class of size 28 has centralizer of order 3. But the centre of the group has order 2, so your numbers cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the center $Z(G) \subseteq C_G(g)$, the centralizer of each $g \in G$. As is well-known, the size of the conjugacy class $Cl_G(g)$ of $g$ is $|G:C_G(g)|$. It follows that $\#Cl_G(g)$ divides $|G:Z(G)|$ for all $g \in G$. The order of the center can be read off the class formula (count the number of $1's$). Hence in your case $|Z(G)|=2$ and $|G:Z(G)|=42$. And clearly $12$ and $28$ do not divide $42$.

Still another approach is the following. Suppose you can find a non-trivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$. Then observe that $N$ is the *disjoint* union of conjugacy classes of $G$, that is $N =\{1\} \cup Cl_G(n_1) \cup \cdots \cup Cl_G(n_t)$ for certain $n_i \in N-\{1\}$. So the conjugacy classes are building blocks of normal subgroups (but not every union of conjugacy classes gives rise to a normal subgroup).
And yes, now we can leverage Sylow Theory. Take $P \in Syl_7(G)$, it is easy to see that $P \lhd G$ (the only divisor of $(84:7)=12$ being $\equiv 1$ mod $7$ is $1$). So by the previous remarks $P=\{1\} \cup$ "some conjugacy classes". But $|P|=7$ and we cannot find distinct conjugacy classes to fill the remaining $6$ elements. Again, a contradiction.